# Is it possible to run a CloudPage locally?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, developer, cloudpage

If you're familiar with CloudPages, you will have noticed the lack of a proper debugger. If the page fails, the only error you get is a "error 500 internal server error", this is not useful at all when you want to solve the error. Also, I sometimes have to wait up to 8 minutes for a change in CloudPages to appear on the page after I published it.

Is it possible to run a CloudPage locally so I can have a proper debugger with useful error messages and I don't have to wait constantly?

Edit: If you're having the same issues and would like to see a debugger implemented in CloudPages, please upvote this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003TD5QAM

Comment: Hopefully someone can answer your question, but in my experience, I've tried to keep the HTML as light-weight as possible by utilizing Code Resources for CSS and javascript (other available too).  That way the wait times are much lower (<1min) for publishing and testing as you go.

Comment: The page is pretty big and complicated unfortunately, and i've refactored and trimmed as much as I could. But the page is still 1400+ lines of code. I think I have to do with the "publish-wait 5 minutes-get useless error message-troubleshoot" method. I wish Salesforce would implement some sort of debugger in CloudPages, that would solve a lot of issues and greatly increase my productivity.

Comment: Agreed. There are some forum members that might be able to provide more insight on how to debug @gornington

Comment: In the meantime, to any people who come here because they have the same problem; please upvote this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003TD5QAM and maybe Salesforce will take a look at it.

Comment: you can submit a ticket to support to get an error log.  You may have know that.  Obviously, THAT can be time consuming too.

Comment: using try{}catch(e){} blocks can really help debug SSJS when combined with the preview trick mentioned by @pkharries. For AMP debugging, setting all variables to '' at the beginning and then running code in blocks/sections is the only (still PITA) way I've found to debug. Open console and use preview to quickly see the 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

@Rutger After wrote the code in Cloud page just preview that one you get debug easily no need to publish every time after change any thing in your code

Comment: I've tried that, but the page doesn't load in preview mode. The load icon just keeps spinning but nothing happens unfortunately.

Comment: @Rutger i think in your code some mistake is there that time only the load icon spinning check your code properly

Comment: In my opinion, the Marketing Cloud previews (both cloudpage & email studio) are VERY lacking and don't reflect actual page/email rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to run the same page as a Landing Page (Microsite).  Here you will gain access to correct debugging errors in both AMPscript and SSJS.